# LDAP: Error while importing ldif file

Tags: apache, ldap

I'm using Apache Directory Studio and I was importing a ldif file into my connection. I noticed this error in my log file. Don't understand what it's saying.

**The Error**

```
# sysPrefRoot, system
#!RESULT ERROR
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.189
#!ERROR [LDAP: error code 65 - OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message ID : 167     Add Request : Entry     dn[n]: prefNodeName=sysPrefRoot,ou=system     objectClass: organizationalUnit     objectClass: extensibleObject     objectClass: top     prefNodeName: sysPrefRoot : ERR_279 Required attributes [ou(2.5.4.11)] not found within entry prefNodeName=sysPrefRoot,ou=system]
dn: prefNodeName=sysPrefRoot,ou=system
prefNodeName: sysPrefRoot
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: extensibleObject
objectClass: top
```

**The Entire Log File**

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <ou=system> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# system
# dn: ou=system
# objectClass: organizationalUnit
# objectClass: extensibleObject
# objectClass: top
# ou: system

# admin, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:42.815
dn: uid=admin,ou=system
uid: admin
keyAlgorithm: RSA
sn: administrator
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: tlsKeyInfo
objectClass: top
displayName: Directory Superuser
cn: system administrator
publicKey:: MFwwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEBBQADSwAwSAJBAIMEVfXIYgLr7RkTOcX2olneNw1C7jA8
 +qonwvYfWhMlDCF5CZON4ni7MjI4MxDnLExbQ9Rnnc8/VqhewiSh9tsCAwEAAQ==
privateKeyFormat: PKCS#8
publicKeyFormat: X.509
privateKey:: MIIBUwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCAT0wggE5AgEAAkEAgwRV9chiAuvtGRM
 5xfaiWd43DULuMDz6qifC9h9aEyUMIXkJk43ieLsyMjgzEOcsTFtD1Gedzz9WqF7CJKH22wIDAQ
 ABAkA9Q+vGcRuT7isDDMB5V+l3SLhJlUC4getdYhaC7Qo75Ovhd+Kjyj8+MhTMhDRFewSEFLBPD
 h/XZZzSWk9SDJYRAiEA1LU36+y3Xu4guvajZAcMoTv5Z+wCXU0UDy6lR5oEkS8CIQCdrr/0K9FK
 6wIGCdYgTbTV86+6Bz/jSbRKbtJ5lg9SFQIgfaGbKeliVNto0YSi9I2FVCXMJSksLFc+JclzLVs
 2n1kCIAWQDKWIhjGmaMPdxPgOxbpmhmSBrPdPulSF5Fb1vEShAiB6htPOSPzXqYlj8DYlJJjpTh
 L3U5x3CWKbNkhyQTWBtQ==
userPassword:: c2VjcmV0
userCertificate:: MIIBczCCAR0CBgE7g79N+jANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBCMQswCQYDVQQGEw
 JVUzEMMAoGA1UEChMDQVNGMRIwEAYDVQQLEwlEaXJlY3RvcnkxETAPBgNVBAMTCEFwYWNoZURTM
 B4XDTEyMTIxMDA3MzczMFoXDTEzMTIxMDA3MzczMFowQjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxDDAKBgNVBAoT
 A0FTRjESMBAGA1UECxMJRGlyZWN0b3J5MREwDwYDVQQDEwhBcGFjaGVEUzBcMA0GCSqGSIb3DQE
 BAQUAA0sAMEgCQQCDBFX1yGIC6+0ZEznF9qJZ3jcNQu4wPPqqJ8L2H1oTJQwheQmTjeJ4uzIyOD
 MQ5yxMW0PUZ53PP1aoXsIkofbbAgMBAAEwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADQQBCsSCLHyTv8chwH6HQH
 FNGIuQqN0kxxzPuzthEpVgf9uVI5HFvt7Y18xDqWlMvHaFy2PcPPcT1bgWMzT11X7MD

# users, system
# dn: ou=users,ou=system
# objectClass: organizationalUnit
# objectClass: top
# ou: users

# groups, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:42.864
dn: ou=groups,ou=system
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: groups

# Administrators, groups, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:42.909
dn: cn=Administrators,ou=groups,ou=system
uniqueMember: 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=admin,2.5.4.11=system
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: Administrators

# configuration, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:42.979
dn: ou=configuration,ou=system
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: configuration

# partitions, configuration, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.065
dn: ou=partitions,ou=configuration,ou=system
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: partitions

# services, configuration, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.124
dn: ou=services,ou=configuration,ou=system
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: services

# interceptors, configuration, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.186
dn: ou=interceptors,ou=configuration,ou=system
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: top
ou: interceptors

# sysPrefRoot, system
#!RESULT ERROR
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.189
#!ERROR [LDAP: error code 65 - OBJECT_CLASS_VIOLATION: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message ID : 167     Add Request : Entry     dn[n]: prefNodeName=sysPrefRoot,ou=system     objectClass: organizationalUnit     objectClass: extensibleObject     objectClass: top     prefNodeName: sysPrefRoot : ERR_279 Required attributes [ou(2.5.4.11)] not found within entry prefNodeName=sysPrefRoot,ou=system]
dn: prefNodeName=sysPrefRoot,ou=system
prefNodeName: sysPrefRoot
objectClass: organizationalUnit
objectClass: extensibleObject
objectClass: top

# system, users, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.276
dn: uid=system,ou=users,ou=system
uid: system
sn: system
userPassword:: e1NIQX1NWDhlZGg4dnFvMm5nYVIySzUzTUxGeXRJSm89
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
cn: system

# admin, users, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.373
dn: uid=admin,ou=users,ou=system
uid: admin
sn: system
userPassword:: e1NIQX0wRFBpS3VOSXJyVm1EOElVQ3V3MWhReE5xWmM9
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
cn: system

# Provider, groups, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.439
dn: cn=Provider,ou=groups,ou=system
uniqueMember: 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=admin,2.5.4.11=system
uniqueMember: uid=angie,ou=users,ou=system
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: Provider

# Service Agent, groups, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.515
dn: cn=Service Agent,ou=groups,ou=system
uniqueMember: 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=admin,2.5.4.11=system
uniqueMember: uid=Hervas,ou=users,ou=system
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: Service Agent

# Service Administrator, groups, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.614
dn: cn=Service Administrator,ou=groups,ou=system
uniqueMember: 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=admin,2.5.4.11=system
uniqueMember: uid=admin,ou=users,ou=system
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: Service Administrator

# System Administrator, groups, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.762
dn: cn=System Administrator,ou=groups,ou=system
uniqueMember: 0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.1=admin,2.5.4.11=system
uniqueMember: uid=system,ou=users,ou=system
objectClass: groupOfUniqueNames
objectClass: top
cn: System Administrator

# Hervas, users, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.856
dn: uid=Hervas,ou=users,ou=system
uid: Hervas
sn: .
userPassword:: e1NIQX1jTmRxUHl6bVVhM2VabHQyRFh4TUx5QW9SeHc9
mail: julie.hervas@state.mn.us
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
givenName: Julie
cn: Julie .
telephoneNumber: 651-431-2704

# angie, users, system
#!RESULT OK
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2013-06-14T13:58:43.942
dn: uid=angie,ou=users,ou=system
uid: angie
sn: angie
mail: angie.c.dezelske@state.mn.us
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
givenName: dezelske
cn: dezelske angie
userPassword:: e1NIQX1yLzB6M3NNYkNFVERlTlM2QlFiQ0wwdy9IT2s9

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 19
# numEntries: 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERR_279 Required attributes [ou(2.5.4.11)] not found within entry prefNodeName

The error message could hardly be clearer. There is no 'ou' attribute specified.

Answer (score 1):

An object class violation means:

- There are attributes in the entry which are not allowed or
- There are attributes which are required but are not present.

Comment: How can I make sure? Where do I look into to match this data?

Comment: In the LDIF file. The entry named in the error msg is either missing required attributes or has attributes which as not permitted by the objectClasses of which the entry is a member.